# Where to put the switch on a power supply? 5V/12V or 230V?

Tags: power-supply, switches

An arcade videogame power supply supplies +5V, +12V and -5V (see [JAMMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Amusement_Machine_and_Marketing_Association)). They usually don't have a switch.

If I were to put a switch on such a power supply, what are the (dis)advantages of interrupting current on the 230 volts versus the +5/+12/-5 volts sides? I probably want to have one for 230 volts, but does it make sense to have the others (or maybe one for all three low voltages) as well? One does often just want to cut power for a few seconds to reboot the arcade system. (As a side note, whether -5V is actually used differs from system to system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you should not switch the +5/+12/-12 V lines as they're not switched now so switching them can cause unpredictable results.

If the system has a push button to power it down, use that and then disconnect the power at the mains (230 V AC) side. Using the push button informs the system to prepare for shutdown. This is similar to how a desktop PC should be fully powered down.

If the system has no way to power it down other than pulling the mains plug then obviously it must be designed to handle that. Then you can safely add a switch on the 230 V AC side. When the console is moved, serviced or there is a mains power interruption then the mains will also "suddenly" disappear right? Adding a mains switch is the same from the console's point of view.

Do make sure you use a switch with the proper voltage and current rating and make sure the user cannot touch the wires carrying mains voltage.

Comment: There are usually no switches at all. An arcade operator will usually just plug the machine in each morning. These system have no shutdown, (usually) no hard drives, mostly just eproms, read-only, etc. Does that change anything,i.e. is it still a bad idea to switch +5V/+12V/-5V? Does it make any difference for the power supply? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything. I still recommend against switching the low voltage supplies since the system probably isn't designed for that so it might give problems eventually. Since on/off is done through AC I would just stick with that. It also saves some power (no standby current) and is also safer. A supply that isn't powered cannot do weird things.